# How to open (or "download") a local file from a website using html?

Tags: html, google-chrome, local

I want to open a local (jpg or pdf) file from a random website (as in not run by me). I know you can edit the html code of a site when it's open in chrome, but when I try to edit the already existing links to link to my local file and then click it, nothing happens. I also know that when you do this, it's not permanent but only lasts untill you close/leave the edited page.

The code I'm replacing the original links with is this:

```
<a href="file:///C:\test.pdf">linkname</a>
```

I read the triple slashes after `file:` should fix it for local run websites, but apperently they don't fix my problem. When I copy `file:///C:\test.pdf` into my file explorer and even my chrome search bar it does work, so I dont understand why it won't work like I want it to.

Could someone please explain and/or help me out? Thanks in advance.

Edit - If anyone knows a workaround for the security block that would be great. It doesn't matter if it downloads or shows the file, all I want it to do is get me the file from the edited link directly (as in it opens/downloads when I click the link, not having to click any other stuff). If you know a less direct solution that would be appreciated as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, HTML in Browsers is not allowed to access a user's File System.

Comment: Okay, that explains it, thanks. Do you know a workaround of some sort? It doesn't matter if it downloads or shows the file, all I want it to do is get me the file from the edited link directly (as in it opens/downloads when I click the link, not having to click any other stuff). Thanks

Comment: You'd need a local server that could fetch the file from its disk(your computer's hard drive).So Now, The link would point to a resource on the server and thus would be available for download.

Comment: Allright, I'll try that then. If you don't hear back from me it probably worked. Thanks for the help :)